# Web Application to Android Application

Tags: android, gmail, web

I have my own email server. I am trying to create an application for Android Phone. As Gmail as a web interface and also Android Gmail apps, where we login and check our email.
I too want to build an application for my own email server like GMAILS.
My Requirements are:
My Android application will have two modes. Firstly SMS Mode and WebView mode. If no wifi or data connection avilable then i would switch to sms mode and i have done it successfully retrieving email list and other functions.
But i too want to use the same above android application for web interface when there is wifi or data connection.

Is my objective achievable. As i am googling around for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it. Though this had nothing to do with i thought. Sorry for troubling you all.